# Finding integer solutions of $m^2-n^5 = m - n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

How to list all integer solutions of

$m^2-n^5 = m - n$

Here $m$ and $n$ are some positive integers.

Also, I want to know the name of this type equations (if name exist).

Regards
Rosy

Comment: A general name of this type of equation is a diophantine equation - an equation which asks for integer (or rational) solutions to polynomial equations.

Comment: Hmm.  Well, $m$ must end in $0$, $1$, $5$, or $6$.  (Because $n^5$ and $n$ end in the same digit, so $m^2$ and $m$ must also end in the same digit.)

Comment: @BrianTung: That's just about $40\%$ of all numbers.

Comment: Yes, I know that. :-)  It wasn't meant to be a complete solution, just an observation off the top of my head.

Answer (score 11):

Write your equation as $m^2 - m = n^5 - n$.
You want $m = (1 + \sqrt{4 n^5 - 4 n + 1})/2$ to be an integer.  Trying the first $10^6$ values of $n$, we find that $4n^5 - 4n + 1$ is a square for 
$n = 1, 2, 3, 30$, corresponding to $m = 1, 6, 16, 4930$.

The curve $x^2 - x - y^5 + y$ has genus $2$ (according to Maple), so by Faltings's theorem there are only finitely many rational points, and in particular only finitely many integer solutions.  I suspect that the solutions I listed are all the positive integer solutions, but  I don't know if it's possible to prove that.

Comment: ! I am looking for general solution which will list all possible solutions in integers.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I would start
(don't know if I will finish):

If $m^2-n^5 = m - n$,
then
$m^2-m = n^5-n$
or
$m(m-1)
=n(n^4-1)
=n(n^2-1)(n^2+1)
=n(n-1)(n+1)(n^2+1)
$.

The RHS needs to factor
into two terms
that differ by $1$.
This seems important,
but I don't know how to
make use of this.

Also,
multiplying by 4 and adding $1$
(to make the left side a square),
$(2m-1)^2
=4m(m-1)+1
=4n(n-1)(n+1)(n^2+1)+1
$.

If $n$ is even,
the RHS is of the form
$8k+1$
where $k$ is odd.

If $n$ is odd,
the RHS is of the form
$64k+1$
where $k$ might be even.

I don't know where to go from here,
so I'll leave it at this.

Comment: ! you have made very good observation. I do not know how to proceed from here. I want to know the general solution for this equation. Still I am trying...

Answer (score 3):

This equation was solved by Bugeaud, Mignotte, Siksek, Stoll and Tengely, see e.g.
http://arxiv.org/pdf/0801.4459v4.pdf

The proof uses linear forms in logarithms and Mordell-Weil sieving. I doubt that there is an easy approach to the problem.

Comment: ! the cited above paper is not clear to me. I think there may be a better and easy approach is there. Please let me know if you guess.

Comment: There is no reason to believe that there is an elementary approach to solve this problem. Sometimes Diophantine equations are just hard.

Comment: Theorem 1 of the linked paper gives all the pairs as $(X, Y ) = (−1, 0), (−1, 1), (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, −5),
(2, 6), (3, −15), (3, 16), (30, −4929), (30, 4930)$

Comment: As the authors mention, the problem was listed as an "open problem" in http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~evertse/07-workshop-problems.pdf .  That's a pretty good indication that there is no easy approach.

Comment: @Ross Millikan! As you said, according to paper link, those 12 set of pairs are solutions. But, I dint find the derivation of getting those pairs. Could you please explain how the paper or you got those pairs?

Comment: @RobertIsrael! Sir, as per your computation using maple, you have given all possible values of m and n up to 10^6. In your list there is no -4929. However, the link of the paper says that -4929 also a solution for it. How?

Comment: @Ross Millikan! your pairs of x and y values are wrong. If you plug (2, -5) or  (2, 6) or rest of your other pairs in x^2 - x = y^5 - y. We can understand that these values are not satisfying the cited above equation. So all your set of pairs from (2, -5) are wrong.

Comment: @rosymilton:  I looked it up again and see I flipped $X$ and $Y$, so the pairs should be reversed.  In fact $(6,2)$ is as solution:  $6^2-2^5=6-2$.  Corrected:  Theorem 1 of the linked paper gives all the pairs as (n,m)=$(−1,0),(−1,1),(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(2,−5),(2,6),(3,−15),(3,16),(30,−4929),(30,4930)$

Comment: @RossMillikan! can we have easy method to get the linked paper solutions? please let me know, if there is an alternative method.

Comment: I am not aware of one.  Is there a reason you think there should be an easy approach?

Answer (score -2):

Let start by eliminating the trivial solutions of the equation: $$m^2-n^5 = m - n$$ which is obviously equivalent to $$m^2-m=n^5-n$$
For instance, $m=n$ or $mn=0$
For I am sure you are looking the non-trivial ones. So we will suppose that $\gcd(m,n)=1$

First observation: According to Fermat's Little Theorem, we have:
$$m^2 \equiv m \pmod 2$$
$$n^5 \equiv n \pmod 5$$
In other words, there exist 2 non-zero integers $s,t \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that:
$$m^2=m+2s$$
$$n^5=n+5t$$
Therefore, 
$$m^2-n^5=m-n+2s-5t=m-n$$
As a result,$$2s=5t$$ From this, it is clear that $2|t$ and $5|s$
Therefore, $$2s=5t\equiv 0 \pmod {10}$$
Then, we can write $$ m^2-m=10k$$
$$n^5-n=10k$$ with $k \in\mathbb{Z} \neq 0$
The first equation can be easily solved by using the quadratic formula:
$$(m-\frac{1}{2})^2=10k+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{40k-1}{4}$$
We must have $40k+1=u^2$ ($u \in\mathbb{Z} \neq 0$),in other words:$$40k=u^2-1=(u-1)(u+1)$$
Clearly, $u$ is odd. Hence, $\gcd(u-1),u+1)=2$. We deduct that one of those prime factors is a multiple of $20k$. Then we write: $$u \pm1=20k'$$ or $$u=20k'\pm 1$$
We then obtain the following values of $m$
$$m= \pm{\frac{20k'+1}{2}}+\frac{1}{2}=\pm 10k'+1$$
$$m= \pm{\frac{20k'-1}{2}}+\frac{1}{2}=\pm 10k'$$

Second Observation: From the system of equations$$ m^2-m=10k$$
$$n^5-n=10k$$ by equating $10k$ we obtain after factorization:
$$m(m-1)=n(n^4-1)$$. According to Gauss lemma, since $\gcd(m,n)=1$ then, $n| m-1$ So there exists an non-zero integer $h$ such that $$m-1=nh$$
From that, we can deduct the values of $n$ knowing the above values of $m$. NOT SURE WHERE TO GO FROM HERE.